# Matplotlib: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I was trying to plots near each other, however this results in error:

```
sns.set_style('darkgrid')
f , axes =plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,15))

sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Month', y='Price', ax=axes[0,0])
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Year', y='Price', ax=axes[0,1])
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/3036328835.py in <module>
      2 f , axes =plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15,15))
      3 
----> 4 sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Month', y='Price', ax=axes[0,0])
      5 sns.boxplot(data=df, x='Year', y='Price', ax=axes[0,1])

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Comment: Can you show `df`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`axes` is 1-dimensional, but you are trying to access as 2-dimensional.  `axes[0]` and `axes[1]` are what you want, or call `subplots(1, 2, squeeze=False)`

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html